# TCL - invalid command name ... but different

Tags: tcl, visibility, procedure, uplevel

I try to add two buttons to the console window for convenience and to play around with it.
The problem is: The first button just triggers an "exit". This works fine.
The second button triggers "LogPuts", which should write all "puts" to a file additionally. It is a toggle button. And this one gives me an "invalid command name LogPuts"

The code itself works, the procedure LogPuts is written *before* the button creation.
Here an example:

```
    proc LogPuts { } { ;#.... do s.th. }

    console eval {
      place [button .console.bExit -text "Exit" -command "exit"] -relx 0.93 -rely 0.0 - 
        width 62 -height 25 
      place [button .console.bLog -text "LogPuts" -command "LogPuts"] ] -relx 0.93 -rely 
        0.06 - width 62 -height 25
    }
```

I even tried to play with uplevel 0 when invoking the button-press to get the procedure noticed on the "toplevel", but since unexperienced with it, the outcome was expected; it did not help :)

Has anyone an idea how to solve this problem? How can I invoke the Button Code in the Console Level?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the documentation at https://www.tcl-lang.org/man/tcl8.6/TkCmd/console.htm#M5 `console eval` uses a separate interpreter from the one used to run normal commands.  The problem here is that you are defining `LogPuts` in the normal interpreter but trying use it from the console interpreter.  The following should work:

```
console eval {
  proc LogPuts { } { ;#.... do s.th. }

  place [button .console.bExit -text "Exit" -command "exit"] -relx 0.93 -rely 0.0 - 
    width 62 -height 25 
  place [button .console.bLog -text "LogPuts" -command "LogPuts"] ] -relx 0.93 -rely 
    0.06 - width 62 -height 25
}
```

Comment: yes, that did it. Thank you! :)
However, I encountered just another problem rightafter, which came due to the nature of the completely separated 'worlds' of console and your regular TCL. I tried to 'trace' the puts command to write it to a file beforehand. This worked fine in normal TCL, but once everything was in the eval-code, .. well, you get different results :).
This was an interesting experiment anyways! But to solve my problem, I seem have to use "chan" to get a hand on stdin and stdout. Well, I have not mastered this yet :). Thanks again for your response.

Comment: Oh, just for the record :) I solved the problem in a twisted way. It could be solved with the use of "consoleintepr". So, now it is essential, that the Logputs stays outside. I just changed the direct call in the button to "LogPuts" in its command to 
"consoleinterp eval { trace add execution puts enter _logputs }"
while "_logputs" is just the outside code that handles writing of the data from puts. Works like a charm :)